# Bower install ngCordova gives error

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

When I type `bower install ngCordova` command, it gives me an error:

[image]

I'm a junior with Ionic Framework.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That Command solved my error and the package installed correctly

```
git config --global url.git://github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/
```

Reference: [Here](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2288)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need set the git certificate location or uninstalled the git and reinstalled it.

Execute the following command on your terminal

```
git config --global http.sslverify "false"
```

For more details please look into [this](https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2288) & [here](https://aircrack.wordpress.com/2014/02/12/problem-solving-git-error-setting-certificate-verify-locations/).

Hopes this well help you !!

Comment: Thanks for your response, that command just solved my error and the package installed correctly `git config --global url.git://github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/`

Comment: If you are working in a place with a proxy be careful, you probably should ask someone to authorize the url and install the certificate on the proxy config. It's for security reasons.